# CanvasJs - Bar graph visibly not updating properly

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, canvasjs

I am trying to loop 3 different charts where the data is updated ever so often.
The datapoints are updated, the charts are updated, but the bars shows the new and old results simultaneously.
[image]

I have tried

- Removing and rebuilding the entire container
- destroy() method
- Resetting the object

But nothing works

Code (Have removed Chart 2 and 3 from draw function for readability):
Edit: Have updated code to include the ajax and main functions as well. Still simplified and renamed due to confidentiality.

```
function ajx() {
  Promise.all([
    $.get({
      url: 'file.html',
      cache: false
    }),
     headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 
        'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
        'Expires': '0'
    }
}),
  ]).then(function(results) {
    main(results)
  }).catch(function(err) {
  });
}

var dateArr = [];
var day = {}

var count = 0;

  var dp = [], 
  target = [],
  colors = []

function main(results) {
  var count = 0;

    //Creating array of dates from the source file
  $(results[0]).find('tbody tr').each(function(i, e) {
    var d = $(this).find(':first-child').text();
    if ($.inArray(d, dateArr) == -1) dateArr.push(d);
  });

    // creating/resetting empty date keys
  for (i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
    day[i] = {
      date: 0,
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0,
      result: 0
    }
  }

  $(results[0]).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var d = $(this).find(':first-child').text();

    //Calculating the results and splitting them by date
    for (i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
      if (dateArr[i] == d) {
        day[i].date = d;
        day[i].value1 += parseInt($(this).find(':nth-child(3)').text());
        for (x = 4; x < 6; x++) {
          day[i].value2 += parseInt($(this).find(':nth-child(' + x + ')').text());
        }
      }
      day[i].result = parseInt(((day[i].value2 / day[i].value1) * 100).toFixed(2));
    }
  });

    //Populating the data points
    for (i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
    dp.push({
      x: new Date(day[i].date),
      y: day[i].result
    })

    //Targets
    target.push({
      x: new Date(day[i].date),
      y: 80
    })

    //Colors
    if (day[i].result < 80) {
      colors.push('red')
    } else {
      colors.push('green')
    }
  }

  CanvasJS.addColorSet("colors", colors);
    setTimeout(ajx, 30000)
}

function drawGraph(x, y) {

  if(y == 1) {
  var x = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    colorSet: "colors",
    animationEnabled: true,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(163,121,143,0)",
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
    axisX: {
      interval: 1,
      intervalType: "day",
      valueFormatString: "MMM DD"
    },
    axisY: {
      stripLines: [{
        value: 80,
        showOnTop: true,
        lineDashType: "dash",
        color: "rgb(51,51,51)",
        thickness: 2
      }],
      includeZero: false,
      suffix: " %"
    },
    legend: {
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: 16
    },
    toolTip: {
      shared: true
    },
    data: [{
      name: "",
      type: "column",
      percentFormatString: "#0.##",
      dataPoints: dp
    }]
  });
    x.render();
    x.destroy();
    x = null;
    }
}



  idx = {
    chartArr: ['chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3']
  }

    //To loop the 3 charts
  function countdown() {
      count++;
      if (count == 1) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[0], count)
      }
      if (count == 2) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[1], count)

      }
      if (count == 3) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[2], count)
      }
      if (count == 3) {
        count = 0;
      }
        setTimeout(countdown, 10000)
  }


ajx();
countdown();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have shared seems to be working fine, after adding sample-data (dp). Please share sample-data along with the code, if you still have any issue!

1. Initial data-points
2. Updated data-points

```js
var dp = [
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 1), y: 71 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 2), y: 55 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 3), y: 50 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 4), y: 65 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 5), y: 95 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 6), y: 68 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 7), y: 28 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 8), y: 34 },
  { x: new Date(2018, 0, 9), y: 14 }
];


function drawGraph(x, y) {

    $('#charts #chartContainer').remove();
    $('#charts').append('<div id="chartContainer" class="chrt" style="visibility: visible;"></div>');

  if(y == 1) {
  var x = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    colorSet: "colors",
    animationEnabled: true,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(163,121,143,0)",
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
    axisX: {
      interval: 1,
      intervalType: "day",
      valueFormatString: "MMM DD"
    },
    axisY: {
      stripLines: [{
        value: 80,
        showOnTop: true,
        lineDashType: "dash",
        color: "rgb(51,51,51)",
        thickness: 2
      }],
      includeZero: false,
      suffix: " %"
    },
    legend: {
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: 16
    },
    toolTip: {
      shared: true
    },
    data: [{
      name: "",
      type: "column",
      percentFormatString: "#0.##",
      dataPoints: dp
    }]
  });
    x.render();
    x.destroy();
    x = null;
    }
}

var idx = {
    chartArr: ['chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3']
  }
  
var count = 0;
countdown();

  function countdown() {
      count++;

      if (count == 1) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[0], count)
      }
      if (count == 2) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[1], count)

      }
      if (count == 3) {
        drawGraph(idx.chartArr[2], count)
      }

      if (count == 3) {
        count = 0;
      }
      
     for(var i = 0; i < dp.length; i++){
      dp[i]. y = Math.random() * 100;
     }
        setTimeout(countdown, 10000)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="charts"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, have updated my post.
The source data is reset and updated on a 5 min interval so I don't see how it can be that, but who knows. You can look through the code above

Comment: Ok I f***d up, I forgot to clear the object within the main function. Your post made me think of it thought so thanks.